# SWIFT: How to refresh textview from array when button pressed?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitextview

I have an array with several strings in it and the textView shows only one string of them (this works already perfectly). But now I want to refresh the textview when I press a button. But it doesn't work. What I tried and doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func refreshButtonDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {
randomizedText()
}
```

randomizedText() is a function where I where I just load my randomized string array. And also I call this function in viewDidLoad so the textView at start is not empty.

Hope you can help.

**Update with the complete code:**

Function randomizedText():

```
func randomizedText() {
    textView.text = randomIdioms
    textView.selectable = false
}
```

randomIdioms is from the following separate extension:

```
extension Int {
    public static func randomIn(#range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
        let difference = range.endIndex - range.startIndex
        let randomPick = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(difference))
        return Int(randomPick) + range.startIndex
    }
}

let idioms = [
    "One Two Test",
    "This is the second exampleThis is the second example",
    "The last exampleThe last exampleThe last exampleThe last example"
]
let randomIdioms = idioms[Int.randomIn(range: 0..<idioms.count)]
```

**Like suggested, now I tried:**

```
@IBAction func refreshButtonDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {
randomizedText()
textView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

But this doesn't work. I can press the refresh button several times without any rerefreshing the textView with another string.

**Next update with working random:**
Instead of using the random generation in the extension, I tried this in my func and call this in @IBAction fun refreshButtonDidPress and it works:

```
func randomizedText() {
    let idioms = ["One Two Test", "This is the second exampleThis is   the second example", "I am not the idiom", "The last exampleThe last exampleThe last exampleThe last example"]
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(idioms.count)))
    textView.text = idioms[index]
    textView.selectable = false
}
```

But I don't have a glue what's wrong in the extension.

Comment: Unless we see what randomizeText does we will not be able to help.

Comment: yeah post the function's code here

Comment: I've updated my initial post with the complete code, also with called textView.setNeedsDisplay() without success.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the `text` property of the `UITextView` to the String you want to display. The `UITextView` doesn't keep a reference to the String you gave it that is in the array. It copies it. The `UITextView` will take care of it's own draw calls and when it needs to be redrawn.

Comment: Here I'm struggling a little bit how to handle this. Do I have to write textView.text = randomText in the refreshButtonDidPress function and also textView.setneedsdisplay()?

Comment: That sounds good. I'm not sure if you even need to call setNeedsDisplay() as changing the text will quite obviously need to update the view, therefore it could take care of calling that itself. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the text view a `setNeedsDisplay()` message. You can do this in your `randomizedText()` function or in `refreshButtonDidPress()` after you call `randomizedText()`.

You will also need to set either the `text` or `attributedText` property on the textView before calling `setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried both but nothing (is not reloading another string) happens with: @IBAction func refreshButtonDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        randomizedText()
        textView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }